# jQuery on click toggle siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to toggle some arrows when i click a certain link, on click action is working but i cannot make the siblings to toggle.

Have any idea what am i missing.

Thanks

HTML code is :

```
<div class="box">
    <span class="info-box-title" >
            <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
            <a class="toggle" href="#yeswebsite"> 
                <b>Website</b>: <?php echo $parsedJson1->website; ?>
            </a>
    </span>
    <div class="arrow-up">&#9650;</div>
    <div class="arrow-down">&#9660;</div>
    <div id="yeswebsite" class="hidden">
        <p>Informatiile privind pagina ta cuprind si adresa de website. Aceasta trimite vizitatorii direct pe siteul tau pentru a afla mai multe informatii. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery Code is

```
$("span>a.toggle").click(function () {
     console.log('it works');
     $(this).siblings(".arrow-up, .arrow-down").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Use: `$(this).parent("span").next(".arrow-up, .arrow-down").toggle();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).siblings(".arrow-up, .arrow-down")` finds siblings of `<a>` and the required elements are siblings of the `<span>`.

```
<span class="info-box-title">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> -------- $(this).siblings() <-+
    <a class="toggle"></a>         --------- $(this)--------------'
</span>
<div class="arrow-up">&#9650;</div>   ---- Required
<div class="arrow-down">&#9660;</div> ---- Required
```

Use `.closest()` to find the parent,

```
$(this).closest('span').siblings(".arrow-up, .arrow-down").toggle();
```